# Pyquery： I'm using pyquery ,the HTTP_REFFER is required in this page,How can i do with it?

Tags: python

the website needs HTTP_REFFER when i send request..
the common way to open pages in PyQuery is `

```
> doc=pyQuery(url=r'http://www.....')
```

how can i add HTTP_REFFER ?

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pyQuery uses urlopen from [urllib.request](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/urllib.request) if you're on py3 or [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) if you're on py2. When you feed it with the url parameter it should either be a string or a [Request](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request) object.

In the python2 case let's see how it would look like if you want to add an http_header to your request:

```
import urllib2
url = urllib2.Request("http://...", headers={'HTTP_REFERER': "http://..."})
doc = pyQuery(url=url)
```

It would be similar in the python3 case. It's always good to read through the code of the libs your're working with, you can find the pyQuery code [here](https://bitbucket.org/olauzanne/pyquery/src/tip/pyquery/pyquery.py).